# Linq query for NULLABLE datetime field

Tags: linq-to-sql

How can I write the linq query to check DateOfBirth is between given date.

Comment: Do you have something currently that isn't working? Care to share it?

Comment: I downvoted your question. You need to provide a more detailed question, with more information. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var IsBetween = (from p in People
                   where p.DateOfBirth.HasValue 
                       && lowDate <= p.DateOfBirth.Value 
                       && p.DateOfBirth.Value <= highDate
                   select true).FirstOrDefault();
```

-or -

```
 var IsBetween = 
        People.Where(p => p.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
              .Select(p => p.DateOfBirth.Value)
              .Any(date => lowDate <= date && date <= highDate);
```

Do you want the search limited to just one person?